# Redirect Page after clicking Submit

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I am wondering how to make it where I click my submit button and the URL doesnt change. Right now when I click it it just sends me the the action page.

The PHP Code is

```html
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])    ||
   empty($_POST['email'])   ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
 echo "No arguments Provided!";
 return false;
   }
 
$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));
 
// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'me@lolnick.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;  
?>
```

I was wondering If someone can help me make it so It stays at the page instead of redirecting.

Comment: Try redirect back using `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`  after finish mailing.

Comment: where would I put that, I tried the end of the code and it didnt work

Comment: never mind. works :). ty

Answer (score 1):

You should use the same page as the action page like:

```
<form action = 'samepage.php'>
  <input type='text' name = 'name'>
  <input type='text' name = 'email'>
  <input type='text' name = 'message'>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])  
...
...
?>
```